# Problem in Android Spinner inside the Tabbars

Tags: android, tabbar

I am making an application and i am facing a problem.

I am using Tab bars and in one of my Tab bar i am using Spinner.

It loads Perfectly but when i click on it. it gives me:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@44647ef8 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

This error.

i am using the following code snippet

```
      ArrayList<String> ageList;
        Spinner age;
        age = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.country);

        ageList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ageList.add("10-20");
        ageList.add("21-35");
        ageList.add("36-60");
        ageList.add("61-100");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ageList);  //array you are populating  
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        age.setAdapter(adapter2);
        age.setSelection(0, true);
```

This code work fine when i am using seperate activity not the tab bars. but in tab bars it gives me the above error exception when i click on the spinner to open a list.

Please guide me Thanks a bunch

Comment: are you using ActivityGroup? By the error it seems you are passing the wrong context.

Comment: please.. can anyone help me atleast :(

Comment: Yes ia m using Activity Group

Comment: So what should i use ? i mean my Activity Group name is SecondGroup and it calls my Activity Age which has the above mentioned code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I m done with this
the problem was with my layout

```
setContentView(R.layout.age)
```

Instead of this i used Layout Inflator as below:

```
 View viewToLoad = LayoutInflater.from(this.getParent()).inflate(R.layout.country, null);
        this.setContentView(viewToLoad);
```

and then called the Spinner n Bingooo! It works Just Perfect

Thanks all of you.. :)